# How do I select a range of columns from a sheet with a gap in the middle

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets

I am writing a Google Apps Script for a Google Sheet and I want to select from a range of columns but exclude several columns in the middle.

I have a sheet resembling

```
+-------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
| Name  | Age | Height | Income | State |
+-------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
| Bob   |  23 |    185 |  50000 | OH    |
| Jim   |  35 |    160 |  23000 | HI    |
| Frank |  24 |    142 |  44565 | CA    |
| Tom   |  24 |    155 |  23758 | NY    |
+-------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
```

And I want to select the first two columns and the last column like so

```
+-------+-----+-------+
| Name  | Age | State |
+-------+-----+-------+
| Bob   |  23 | OH    |
| Jim   |  35 | HI    |
| Frank |  24 | CA    |
| Tom   |  24 | NY    |
+-------+-----+-------+
```

`sheet.getRange()` works well enough getting a continuous range but what is the most compact way to combine two ranges with the same number of rows?

Answer (score 1):

If `Name` is in A1, I suggest:

```
=query(A:E,"select A,B,E")
```

or copy/paste the entire table and delete the surplus columns.

Answer (score 1):

the most simple (and faster than `QUERY`) is to use `FILTER` or `ARRAYFORMULA` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A:B, E:E})
```

---

```
=FILTER({A:B, E:E}, A:A<>"")
```

[image: 0]